# Exercise 7.3 Think Python book

Tags: python

> The mathematician Srinivasa Ramanujan found an inﬁnite series that can
>   be used to generate a numerical approximation of 1/π:
>
> [image]
>
> Write a function called estimate_pi that uses this formula to compute
>   and return an estimate of π. It should use a while loop to compute
>   terms of the summation until the last term is smaller than 1e-15
>   (which is Python notation for 10**−15). You can check the result by
>   comparing it to math.pi.

Although both my solution and the correct answer(which I found in internet) are similar logically, but I don't understand why my factorial function does't work properly for this question. (It traps on an infinite loop when I use it in the calculation of pi.) When I check my factorial function separately it works correctly but only for this question it seems I must follow different structure.

My code:

```
import math

def fact(n):

    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return (n * fact(n - 1))        



k = 0
result = 0

while True:

    result = result + ( ( fact(4*k)*(1103 + 26390*k))    /    ((fact(k)**4) 
* (396 ** (4*k))) )

    if abs(result) < 1e-15:
        break

    k = k + 1

print ("result = ", (2 * math.sqrt(2) / 9801) * result)
print("pi = ",math.pi)
```

correct one:

```
import math

def fact(n):

    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        recurse = fact(n-1)
        result = n * recurse
        return result




k = 0
result = 0

while True:

    result = result + ( ( fact(4*k)*(1103 + 26390*k))    /    ((fact(k)**4) 
* (396 ** (4*k))) )

    if abs(result) < 1e-15:
        break

    k = k + 1

print ("result = ", (2 * math.sqrt(2) / 9801) * result)
print("pi = ",math.pi)
```

Comment: Your statement "my factorial function does't work properly for this question" is vague. Exactly when and how does it not work? How are you sure that is the problem? Also, your formula in the first paragraph makes no sense. Please show it in a better way--as validated Python code or as an image. (It is unfortunate that StackOverflow does not support MathJax.)

Comment: All that is too cramped for a comment, and I cannot read or understand it. I added the most important part to your question. I also added a graphic of Ramanujan's formula, taken from my PDF of *Think Python, 2nd Edition* and made clear just what the problem from the book is, as distinct from your question. If you continue to ask questions here that is the kind of thing you should do yourself to attract good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your factorial function is fine. I checked it for all values of `n` up to 100, which is much more than is needed for this problem. (It could be made more efficient, but that is a different question.)

Your problem is the same as in the "correct answer(which [you] found in internet)"--that so-called "correct" code is not correct at all. You can find actual correct code at [this web page](http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/code/pi.py), which is the official answer from the author of the book *Think Python, 2nd Edition*.

The problem statement says to "compute terms of the summation until the last term is smaller than 1e-15". However, you never actually test the *term*--you instead test the *partial sum*, which is the term plus the previous partial sum. In other words, in your expression

```
result = result + ( ( fact(4*k)*(1103 + 26390*k))
                  / ((fact(k)**4) * (396 ** (4*k))) )
```

`result` is the *partial sum* while the *term* is the right hand side when you remove the variable `result`. You never store the term anywhere so you never test it so you never stop properly. You check the partial sum `result` which grows and never becomes small, so you have an infinite loop.

Check the code I linked to for a proper answer that tests each term. There are also some other differences between your code and the official answer. You should spend some time to discover and understand the differences. For one thing, you never did "Write a function called estimate_pi".

Comment: I understand it, finally. Thanks alot